# How to set up max post size for Tomcat in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a client server application using Spring Shell on the client side and Spring boot(2.5.7) on the server side. We use Tomcat server and use TomcatServletWebServerFactory to create it. I want to provide a specific value for max post size to the server programmatically. I read some articles and can see that Connector class can be used to customize the server. However I am not finding a suitable code. Can someone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the following property ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size))

```
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size
```